# A drive changes device file name after resuming from suspend (Linux Mint 14)

Tags: mount, devices, suspend

I'm running into a very odd problem: When I resume Mint 14 from suspend, one of my drives (/dev/sdc) changes letter / device file name (to /dev/sdd). `fdisk -l` shows that it has the same partitions, but anything mounted to it becomes inaccessible (even though they are mounted by UUID).

This started happening after I installed another drive, which ended up becoming /dev/sda.

Any ideas what's going on?

Comment: Is sdc a normal SATA drive or a USB drive?

Comment: @HaukeLaging It's a SATA drive.

Comment: Can you provide `dmesg` output after resuming? Just enough to include messages from when the system was going into suspend, and then after waking.

Answer (score -1):

For a *very* long time now, device names aren't stable. Many times they *seem* to be (because by chance they get asigned the same name each time, as the device enumeration is mostly deterministic).

Just live with it, mount your devices by UUID.

Comment: I am afraid you have to read better what he wrote.

Comment: @HaukeLaging, I did read what OP wrote. When the kernel starts, it enumerates the devices, and they show up in the order in which they "wake up" (and get asigned names in that order). Clear now?

Comment: @vonbrand I don't actually care that it changes letter, but I can't read anything mounted on that drive after this happens (even though it's mounted by UUID).

Comment: @vonbrand Hard to believe. You tell the OP to mount by UUID though he told us that he did right that. Changing major/minor numbers after suspend is inacceptable in all cases and obviously a kernel bug.